# jQuery, how to animate overlay opacity, with image in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to animate a overlay using opacity when you hover the element, however it does not work. I can easily do it without the animation, but I would like to get a fade effect. I'm trying to achieve this with jQuery.

I want the overlay to not be visible when the image is hovered.

Take look at below jsfiddle-example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jem2M/1/

I've been looking for examples, but most of them use fadeIn and fadeOut, and I can't use that because the element should always be visible, only the opacity should change on hover.

**Solved:**
Forgot to enclose the selector. Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jem2M/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.bghover #background img')` - you forgot (twice) to enclose your selector into quotes.

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jem2M/4/

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Glad you noticed!

Answer (score 0):

I've just opened http://jsfiddle.net/jem2M/4/ (using my chrome 21) and it works fine. When you mouse over the image it animates the opacity to 1 , and when the mouse goes out the opacity is modified to 0.75